# How to have #description in form to be below title and above field?

Tags: forms

How can I place Description below Title and above field ?

```
 $form['term-selection']['autocomplete'] = array(
      '#title' => variable_get('autocomplete_sync_shs_autocomplete_headline',t('Type in directly')),
      '#description' => variable_get('autocomplete_sync_shs_autocomplete_info',t('')),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#autocomplete_path' => 'third-level-auto-suggest/autocomplete-taxonomy-term/'.$field_name.'/'.$entity_type.'/' . $node_type ,
      '#states' => array(
         'disabled' => array(
           ':input[name="widget-selection"]' => array('value' => 1 ),
         ),
      ),
      '#default_value' => $default_autocomplete,
    );
```

The output I get is 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

User #after_build at the end of your hook_form_alter.

```
$form['#after_build'][] = 'MODULE_NAME_move_description_up_after_build';
```

See below function to move the description in between the title and field.

```
/**
 * build function
 * @param type $form
 * @param type $form_state
 * @return type
 */
function MODULE_NAME_move_description_up_after_build($form, $form_state) {
  drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("label ~ div.description").each(function(index, element) {
      $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev("input"));
    });
  });', array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5));

  return $form;
}
```